# Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. this error is bugging me

Tags: google-chrome

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

The error appears on every page I load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You did not have this function 
**chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((req, sen, response) => { console.log(req)})**

at the receiving end.

 If u are sending message from serviceworker.js then foreground.js should content that above function.